# Best Practice for Jquery $.Ready Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I've a lots of MVC3.0 partial views which can be reused on multiple pages. Each partial views have their own JavaScript with JQuery $.Ready function.

I'm wondering if anyone can help me on what's the best practice of using `$.ready` per below:

1. Should I create Ready.js which contains all the events/functions that should go under `$.ready`? And refer on master layout page.
2. or each page should have their own.
3. What happens when `$.ready` function executes and can't find an element being referred since the partial view page is not being used for that page.
4. What are the best practices to organize the JavaScript in general, i.e. js for each page/widget/control?

Comment: It depends. Sometimes it makes sense to keep code only with the page it's needed on, other times it makes more sense to organize it all into a single place. if a jQuery method is called on an empty collection of elements, nothing will happen.

Comment: 3) [`$().ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) does not look for any elements, so it doesn't matter if it can't find any.

Comment: Not sure you'll find a best practice. Many senior developers swear that having multiple .ready is bad practice. I try to avoid it, but I've never seen it cause a functional problem. And so, you will find very little about best practices

Answer (score 2):

Use this [article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/14-helpful-jquery-tricks-notes-and-best-practices/)

> ```
> $(document).ready(function() {  
>     // let's get up in heeya  
> });
> ```
>
> Though, it’s very possible that you might have come across a
>   different, more confusing wrapping function.
>
> ```
> $(function() {  
>     // let's get up in heeya  
> });
> ```
>
> Though the latter is somewhat less readable, the two snippets above
>   are identical. Don’t believe me? Just check the jQuery source.
>
> ```
> // HANDLE: $(function)  
> // Shortcut for document ready  
> if ( jQuery.isFunction( selector ) ) {  
>     return rootjQuery.ready( selector );  
> }
> ```
>
> rootjQuery is simply a reference to the root jQuery(document). When
>   you pass a selector to the jQuery function, it’ll determine what type
>   of selector you passed: string, tag, id, function, etc. If a function
>   was passed, jQuery will then call its ready() method, and pass your
>   anonymous function as the selector.